# Converting Dataframe column with list objects to floating point numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a JSON file into a dataframe. The dataframe I created has two columns: `time` and `sumOfFFT`. They both are floating point numbers. While `sumOfFFT` is of type float, `time` is of the type object and each row in the column is a `list` with the number in it.

I tried using `to_numeric` and all the digits get converted to NaN since it's a `list` object. I also tried Series but that did the same. I am trying to convert the list object in every row to a string and then float but it throws an error.

```
a = float(str(frame.iloc[1]['time']))
print(a)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-2f41310a23f7> in <module>()
----> 1 a = float(str(frame.iloc[1]['time']))
      2 print(a)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[0.0001041666667]'
```

Data format:

```
{
    "fft": {
        "time": [
            [0],
            [0.0001041666667],
            [0.0002083333333],
            [0.0003125],
                        ],
        "sumOfFFT": [2.883648107,2.769599456,2.659837554,2.560352381]
                }
}
```

Code so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('akhil_195682_170628-174745.json') as json_data:
   obj = json.load(json_data)
   frame = pd.DataFrame(obj['fft'], columns=['time', 'sumOfFFT'])
```

Output:

```
time    sumOfFFT
0   [0] 2.883648
1   [0.0001041666667]   2.769599
2   [0.0002083333333]   2.659838
3   [0.0003125] 2.560352
```

I expect to convert the data into a DataFrame, and plot the two variables against each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
frame["time"]=frame["time"].apply(lambda x:x[0])
```

Result:

```
    sumOfFFT    time
0   2.883648    0.000000
1   2.769599    0.000104
2   2.659838    0.000208
3   2.560352    0.000313
```